# how to write MST algorithium in JAVA?

Tags: java, kruskals-algorithm, prims-algorithm

Problem with MST algorithium in JAVA?

I am trying to  write code  for MST in java

Here, graph is already given and 
I am trying to write addCheapest method to  add node (not on the path) that when added to the path,  at some position, MINIMIZES the resulting cost of the path over all nodes in the graph and all positions they can be added; add  it to that position.

```
private void addCheapest(List<String> path)

Here's what I wrote so far....


private void addCheapest(List<String> path){


g.getAllEdges();


int minEdge = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

int edgeValue = g.getEdgeValue(edge);

for (Edge e : g.getAllEdges())
  {
      if ( edgeValue < minEdge)
          g.getAllEdges() = minEdge;
  }

  while ( g != null)
  {
      g.removeNode(nodeName);
      for ( int i = 0; i < path.size(); i ++)
      {
          if (!path.contains(nodeName))
              path.add(nodeName);
      }
  }
```

}*

Comment: Consider improving your question: a statement like "its not working" means nothing to someone who doesn't have access to your code. A small working example that others can run would greatly improve the chances of receiving help. Explain what the output of this little example is and, more importantly, how that differs from the expected/desired output.

Comment: You should add some comments.. I really can't figure out what you want to do with some statements...

Answer (score 1):

Without digging deep into theory of this question and graph algorithms, this won't work:

`int minEdge = Integer.MIN_VALUE;` and then `if ( edgeValue < minEdge)`

because `minEdge` is already as small as possible. You should set `minEdge` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` instead

Comment: Thanks ! That was miss typed, I guess otherwise its silly trying to find lesser value then minimum integer value.  I need help for add\ding the edge Value in the path that is cheapest.